# Object generated with Shell returns Error 91 Object variable not set

Tags: vba, shell, ms-access, ftp

I had working code for FTP uploads sending files to a server.

I now get an error when executing

```vb
ftpFolder.CopyHere lokalFolder.Items.Item((Dateiname))
```

The error is

> Error 91 Object variable not set

which could mean one of those errors on the official [Microsoft Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91). The code was running until a few weeks ago.
I checked all the point out of the doc so far and tested my code.

Could it be because I synchronised my PC with OneDrive and the paths contain spaces? Or is it because the Shell.Application Object is used wrongly?

The PC is synced with OneDrive, so the string for the current Project path would look something like: C:...\Onedrive\CompanyName GmbH & Co. KG\Desktop

```vb
Option Explicit
 
 
Public Enum LadeTyp
   ltDownload
   ltUpload
End Enum
 
#If 0 Then 'Schutz vor Überschreiben
Dim ltDownload, ltUpload
#End If
 
 
Public Sub FTPLoad(ByVal Laderichtung As LadeTyp, _
                   Server As String, _
                   Benutzer As String, _
                   passwort As String, _
                   LokalerOrdnerpfad As String, _
                   Optional Dateiname As String, _
                   Optional RemoteOrdnerpfad As String)
 
   ' Late Binding, kein Verweis auf 'Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation' erforderlich
 
   Dim objShell          As Object  ' Shell32.Shell
   Dim ftpFolder         As Object  ' Shell32.Folder
   Dim lokalFolder       As Object  ' Shell32.Folder
   Dim fi                As Object  ' Shell32.FolderItem
   Dim strFTPVerbindung  As String
 
   ' Slash am Pfadanfang entfernen
   If Left(RemoteOrdnerpfad, 1) = "/" Then
     RemoteOrdnerpfad = Mid(RemoteOrdnerpfad, 2)
   End If
 
   strFTPVerbindung = "ftp://" & Benutzer & ":" & passwort & "@" & Server & "/" & RemoteOrdnerpfad
 
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 
   ' Argument in doppelte Klammern bei Late Binding
   Set ftpFolder = objShell.Namespace((strFTPVerbindung))
   Set lokalFolder = objShell.Namespace((LokalerOrdnerpfad))
 
   ' Ordner
   If Dateiname = vbNullString Then
 
      If Laderichtung = ltDownload Then
 
         ' Ganzen Ordner herunterladen
         lokalFolder.CopyHere ftpFolder
 
      ElseIf Laderichtung = ltUpload Then
 
         ' Ganzen Ordner hinaufladen
         ftpFolder.CopyHere lokalFolder
 
      End If
 
   ' Datei
   Else
 
      If Laderichtung = ltDownload Then
 
         ' Erste Datei im Ordner über ihren Index ansprechen,
         ' um die Dateigröße 0 bei der heruntergeladenen Datei zu vermeiden.
         ' Der Fehler wurde vermutlich inzwischen von Microsoft behoben.
         ' Set fi = ftpFolder.Items.Item(0)
 
         ' Datei herunterladen
         ' Argument in doppelte Klammern bei Late Binding
         lokalFolder.CopyHere ftpFolder.Items.Item((Dateiname))
 
      ElseIf Laderichtung = ltUpload Then
 
         ' Datei hinaufladen
         ' Argument in doppelte Klammern bei Late Binding
         ftpFolder.CopyHere lokalFolder.Items.Item((Dateiname))
 
      End If
 
   End If
 
End Sub
```

My Code to call:

```vb
*generated a file and saved as test.csv in CurrentProject.Path*

...

strUser = "MyUser"
strPassword = "MyPass"
strServer = "ftp.myserver.com"
        
strRelRemotePfad = "/path/"
strPfadLokalerOrdner = CurrentProject.Path
strPfadLokalerDateiname = "test.csv"
        
Call FTPLoad(ltUpload, strServer, strUser, strPassword, _
                strPfadLokalerOrdner, strPfadLokalerDateiname, strRelRemotePfad)
```

Comment: Shell sometimes prefers a Variant to a String when passing arguments to its methods: you might try switching your Strings declarations to variants